# Optimizing dataset with a composite primary key that includes a status field

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, primary-key

I might be over thinking things, but I am considering opportunities to optimize a large dataset. I have a table schema whose contents is primarily grabbed with its primary key and a status field. Is there any optimization that can be done if I somehow included the status field as part of a composite primary key to speed up search? So for example my table schema might be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE object_t (
    object_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR CHECK (status ~ '(Astatus|Bstatus|Cstatus|Dstatus)'),
    contents TEXT
);
```

My queries will almost always be something like

```
SELECT * FROM object_t WHERE search condition AND status = ...
```

Is there any advantage here for large datasets to adjust the schema to have:

```
PRIMARY KEY (object_id, status)
```

Further, tables that I join with this table also always include that status filter. Should I then adjust foreign key constraints to be something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (object_id, status) REFERENCES object_t (object_id, status)
```

Is there any optimization to be gained here, or is simply operating with the object_id and status filter as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1):

The index you suggest will very likely *not* help.

It only offers a benefit if there is also a condition similar to this in the query:

```
WHERE object_id = ? AND status = ?
```

If only `status` is in the `WHERE` condition, the index cannot be used at all.

The name `status` suggests that there are not very many different values. That means that such a condition is often not very selective, which speaks against indexing it.

If you allways query for a certain `status`, a partial index can be helpful.

But the best thing you can do is experiment.